# Finding whether a number is prime or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function isPrime(num) {
  let result = true;
  if (num < 2) {
    result = false;
    return result;
  }

  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      result = false;
      break;
    }

  }
  return result;
}
```

I am trying to find whether a given number is prime or not, why is my code not executing in a limited amount of time?

Comment: What do you mean with *executing in a limited amount of time*?

Comment: Where are you calling your function?

Comment: What do you define as a "limited amount of time"? This code seems to run perfectly fine, even with numbers in the millions.

Comment: *"why is my code not executing in a limited amount of time?"* - Is the code **failing** in some way, or is there some test you're executing which expects better performance for large input values?  What is your input value in that test?  If the problem is that the code is too slow for large input values, have you done any research on efficient algorithms to determine if a number is prime?

Comment: I would recommend using Fermat's little theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: My code doesn’t respond on some numbers, with large numbers it just takes too much time. But i just found a way to iterate i till square root of the number by using math.sqrt(num) for better efficiency. Still looking for the issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

By defintion a prime number is a whole number greater than 1 whose only factors are 1 and itself.
So you need to count how many factors does it have. If it has 2 factors then it is prime number.

```
    function isPrime(num) {
        let result = true;
        if (num < 2) {
            result = false;
        return result;
        }
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
           count++
            }
        }
        if (count === 2 ){
            return true
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: I have already considered 1 and the number itself, that’s why the iteration starts from 2 and i am only looking for a third number to decide whether it is prime or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two nice one-liners for the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem):

```
// this works with normal ints, may break with big numbers (please see notes)
const isPrime = n => n == 2 || ( n&1 == 1 && (2**(n-1))%n == 1 )

// this works with BigInts
const isPrime = n => n == 2n || ( n&1n == 1n && (1n<<(n-1n))%n == 1n )
```

The second one simply uses BigInts (and bit shifting), but at core works like the first one.

Let me break the code down for you:

1. `const isPrime = n => ...` is a function definition
2. `... || ...`  is a lazy OR: if the first condition is true it will end the "execution" and return true (false is returned if neither one does)
3. `n == 2` checks for the only even prime number
4. `n&1 == 1` checks if the number is odd
5. `... && ...` is a lazy AND (if n is odd, it could be prime)
6. `(2**(n-1))%n == 1` let Fermat's little theorem do its magic

Please note that this thereom is slow for big numbers, but if you only care about performance, then you should think about a different language.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a reason that why my code doesn’t respond on some numbers.